# Mirror WebSite download specific file type with BASH

Tags: bash, http, wget, mirror

I am trying to archive collections from several websites. I want to be able to maintain them is some sort of organization. So it would be ideal to store them in a mirrored dir structure. Below is my attempt

```
wget -m -x -e robots=off --no-parent --accept "*.ext" http://example.com
```

While using the "-m" option does it have any limit on how far it goes? (will it wander off the the web-site? go forever?) if so, is it better to use

```
wget -r -x -e robots=off --no-parent --accept "*.ext" --level 2 http://example.com
```

Is this the most reasonable way to do this? I know that "wget" has a --spider option, Is it stable?

> EDIT

**This is the solution I have found.**

The files I was looking for are tagged and stored in a single `dir` on the server side. When trying variations of `wget`. I was able to get structure of the links and various files but I kept having trouble with links running in loops. So I came up with this work around. It works but is slow. Any advice on how to increase efficiency?

**The structure of website & files that I am trying to get**

```
home
   ├──Foo
   │  ├──paul.mp3
   │  ├──saul.mp3
   │  ├──micheal.mp3
   │  ├──ring.mp3
   ├──Bar
      ├──nancy.mp3
      ├──jan.mp3
      ├──mary.mp3
```

So first I created,
**The file with the TAGS of the files that I want**

```
taglist.txt
foo
bar
```

**The Script**

```
#!/bin/bash

#this script seems to work until the download part


URL="http://www.example.com"
LINK_FILE=taglist.txt

while read TAG; do
    mkdir "$TAG"
    cd "$TAG"

        # Get the URLs from the page
        wget -q $URL/$TAG -O - | \tr "\t\r\n'" '   "' | \grep -i -o '<a[^>]\+href[ ]*=[ \t]*"\(ht\|f\)tps\?:[^"]\+"' | \sed -e 's/^.*"\([^"]\+\)".*$/\1/g' > tmp.urls.txt
        # Clean and sort URLs
        grep -i 'http://www.example.com/storage_dir/*' tmp.urls.txt | sort -u > tmp.curls.txt
            # Download the page with the URL
            while read TAPE_URL; do
            #wget -r -A.mp3 $TAPE_URL
            wget -O tmp.$RANDOM $TAPE_URL
            done <tmp.curls.txt
            # Find all the .mp3 links in the files
            grep -r -o -E 'href="([^"#]+)[.mp3]"' * | cut -d'"' -f2 | sort | uniq > $TAG.mp3.list
            # Clean Up
            rm tmp.* 
            # Download the collected URLs
            wget -i $TAG.mp3.list
    cd ..   
done <"$LINK_FILE"
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading the `man` page for `wget`, you'll see the following answers to your questions:

- `-m` is equivalent to `-r -N -l inf --no-remove-listing`, which means that it will (A) recurse, (B) only download a file from the server if it is newer than the version you already have, (C) not limit itself to any recursion depth, and (D) keep placeholder files along the way to make sure all files have been fetched.
- yes, recursion will follow links wherever they may go, which is why there is a default recursion depth of 5.  By using `-m`, however, you are turning off the depth limit, so you could potentially download the entire internet to your computer.  That's why you should read the **Recursive Accept/Reject Options** section of the `man` page.  It tells you all about how to limit the recursion.  For example, you can specify that only links within a certain domain are followed.
- `-r` with `--level 2` will certainly restrict your recursion, but it will (A) not guarantee that you don't visit other sites, and (B) almost certainly miss a large amount of the site that you do want to mirror
- `--spider` is not for downloading files; it's just for visiting pages.

Note that even with the `-m` directive you will most likely still not capture *all* the files you need to truly mirror an entire site.  You'll need to use the `-p` option to get all the page prerequisites for every page you visit.